# git clone access error specifying a destination directory

Tags: git, bundler

I'm trying to clone (actually, Bundler is) a repository specifying a destination directory:

```
git clone 'git@bitbucket.org:org/repo.git' \
  "/home/maurizio/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache/bundler/git/repo-34ec47fae53fea1f1a83aa12476ce783204fcfef" \
  --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet
```

This command fails with the following error message:

```
Forbidden
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I tried to manually run the command, and I get the same error, **unless** I remove the destination directory:

```
git clone 'git@bitbucket.org:org/repo.git' \
  --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet
```

As a workaround, I'm manually cloning it and moving it after the clone.

My setup is pretty the default one; I just have an alternative SSH key for this project, saved as `~/.ssh/id_rsa_org`, which is working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not properly specifying the path of the destination directory that's why it's showing that error. Instead, try to get into the destination directory, open the terminal there and try 
`git clone 'git@bitbucket.org:org/repo.git' \
  --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet`